# Example for opencv groupRectangle in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to ask regarding groupRectangles function.

I am writing the following code in python -

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#defining the face
thresh=1
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
print faces
faces_1,weights=cv2.groupRectangles(faces, thresh)
```

where vec is the returning recl from the detectMultiscal step, 1 is the groupThreshold and eps is 0.2

But it is throwing me a runtime error while executing. I tried to run the code by using try-except but still it is throwing me the same error.

```
Runtime Error!

Program:C:\Python27\pythonw.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
```

It will be of great help if someone can provide some sample grouprectangle code in python, so that i can make my working code in the same format, as in the documentation of this code i am unable to find any examples.

Cheers!

Comment: please provide the error and more complete Code (including the call off detectMultiscale)

Comment: faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
 , faces_1=cv2.groupRectangles(faces,1,0.2), where face_cascade is the haar classifier

Comment: How about writing it down?

Comment: Do you know exactly where the error occurs? (On which line?) If not try to find out be commenting out the code line by line.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
I managed to make it not crash (but I don't know if the results are accurate) by casting to a "list":

```
cv2.groupRectangles(list(rectVec), thresh)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation off the two functions is:

```
cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize]]]]]) → objects¶

cv2.groupRectangles(rectList, groupThreshold[, eps]) → rectList, weights
```

This suggests the following usage:

```
casc = cv2.CascadeClassifier(filename)
rectVec = casc.detectMultiScale(im)
thresh = 1
rectList, weights = cv2.groupRectangles(rectVec, thresh)  # eps is optional
```

---

I just double checked that above code is working for me. 
Make sure that your OpenCV Version and Python bindings are up to date (my OpenCV Version is 2.4.6.1) and that all your inputs have the right format (classifier file, input image).

Comment: Hi @Mailerdaimon, thank you very much for your answer. I had tried this approach yesterday but still it is throwing me the same run time error and simultaneously my python shell is also getting crashed

Comment: If the error occurs on `groupRectangles`: Try to print the output of `detectMultiScale` and make sure it is as expected.

Comment: Than you really need to write that error down and edit it in your question. Without that information there is not much to do.

Comment: Hi @Mailerdaimon, my opencv version is 2.4.8. and I am using Python 2.7.5

Comment: This looks good, than try investigating where exactly the error occurs and double check your inputs. The runtime error suggests that the error is happening somewhere in the C-Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking issues regarding bounding box merge.
Morphology is what you need to understand. 
Note: Don't use random color to produce random bounding box. Morphology technique fails unless you want to do it manually.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html